# powershell script to merge .csv files by filename prefix

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm currently trying to compare and merge .csv files that are named "xxx_yyy_zzz" by their respective filenames in Powershell. All files having the same "xxx_yyy" patterns are supposed to be merged into a single .csv file that is named "xxx_yyy", preferably into the same directory.

I'm using for-loops and and ArrayList right now (I tried grouping the objects to use -Split or -SkipLast but had trouble with already existing merged files being read again). I got the comparison down (mostly), but I can't seem to merge the .csv files with the Import/Export commands.

The files are being created and their names are correct, but they are always empty. I'm not sure I fully understand the correct usage oft Export-CSV and how to get multiple files into the command... Any help?

Here is my code:

```
$array = @((Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\neich\Documents\ConvertXLSXToCSV\Testfolder' -Name )) #declare the array
$matchArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList #declare ArrayList

#for-loop grabs each file, splits the filename (for comparisons) and adds the filename to an ArrayList
for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) { 
    $filearray = @((Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\neich\Documents\ConvertXLSXToCSV\Testfolder' -Name )) 
    $filenameArray = $filearray[$i].Split("_") 
    $match1 = $filearray[$i] 
    [void]$matchArrayList.Add($match1) #void suppresses the return of indices

        #second for-loop iterates over the files to compare them to fhe first one, if-statements ensure that only files "after" the first one are checked;
        #matches are added to the ArrayList
        for ($ii=$i; $ii -lt $array.length; $ii++) { 
            $filearray2 = @((Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Users\neich\Documents\ConvertXLSXToCSV\Testfolder' -Name ))
                if($i -lt $ii) { 
                    $filenameArray2 = $filearray2[$ii].Split("_") 
                        if($filenameArray[0] -eq $filenameArray2[0] -and $filenameArray[1] -eq $filenameArray2[1] -and !($filenameArray[2] -eq $filenameArray2[2])) {     # Check for matching prefixes and different endings     
                            $match2 = $filearray[$ii]           
                            [void]$matchArrayList.Add($match2) 
                }
        }
    } #end of $ii for-loop

    #for-loop is supposed to import all files from the ArrayList and merge them into a single .csv;
    #ArrayList is cleared at the end for the following iterations of the first for-loop
    if ($filenameArray[2]) { #prevents already merged files from being merged again (since they only have two indices)
       $mergedName = $filenameArray[0] + "_" + $filenameArray[1]
       $pathNameExport = "C:\Users\neich\Documents\ConvertXLSXToCSV\Testfolder\" + $mergedName + ".csv" 
         for ($iii = 0; $iii -lt $matchArrayList.Count; $iii++) {
            $pathNameImport = "C:\Users\neich\Documents\ConvertXLSXToCSV\Testfolder\" + $matchArrayList[$iii]
             IMPORT-CSV $pathName | Export-Csv -Path $pathNameExport -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
             #insert code to delete matches(WIP)
         } #end of $iii for-loop
    }
$matchArrayList.Clear()
} #end of $i for-loop
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used the raw data (get-content | selct-object -skip 2) instead of import csv. Then we use a foreach loop and an array to append the other file to then we export this full array using set-content to over write the file. Its a hacky fix but it worked for me in less time than and lines then any other script i tried to build for it.

Comment: Np, sometimes not thinking will get you the most #100% all of my scripts

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. Just modify the path in the first line and it works

```
$path = "C:\Users\neich\Documents\ConvertXLSXToCSV\Testfolder" #set Path to .csv directory
$array = @((Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Name )) #declare the array
$matchArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList #declare ArrayList

#for-loop grabs each file, splits the filename (for comparisons) and adds the filename to an ArrayList
for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) {
    $filearray = @((Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Name ))

  if ($filearray[$i]) {
    $filenameArray = $filearray[$i].Split("_") 
    $match1 = $filearray[$i] 
    [void]$matchArrayList.Add($match1) #void suppresses the return of indices
        #second for-loop iterates over the files to compare them to fhe first one, first if-statement ensures that only files "after" the first one are checked; 
        #last if-Statement compares the first two substrings and makes sure the third one mismatches (prevents already merged files to be merged again)
        #matches are added to the ArrayList
        for ($ii=$i; $ii -lt $array.length; $ii++) { 
            $filearray2 = @((Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Name ))
                if($i -lt $ii) {
                    if ($filearray2[$ii]) {
                    $filenameArray2 = $filearray2[$ii].Split("_") 
                        if($filenameArray[0] -eq $filenameArray2[0] -and $filenameArray[1] -eq $filenameArray2[1] -and !($filenameArray[2] -eq $filenameArray2[2])) {     # Check for matching prefixes and different endings     
                            $match2 = $filearray[$ii]           
                            [void]$matchArrayList.Add($match2) 
                         }
                     }
                 }
         } #end of $ii for-loop

 
    #if-Statement prevents already merged files from being merged again (since they only have two indices)
    if ($filenameArray[2]) {
       $mergedName = $filenameArray[0] + "_" + $filenameArray[1]
       $pathNameExport = $path + "\" + $mergedName + ".csv" 
         
         #for-loop iterates over all matches, extracts the data and adds it to a new file. Matches are then deleted to prevent redundancy in further $i + $ii loops
         for ($iii = 0; $iii -lt $matchArrayList.Count; $iii++) {
            if ($matchArrayList[$iii]) {
                $pathNameImport = $path + "\" + $matchArrayList[$iii]
                $export = Get-Content -Path $pathNameImport
                $export | Add-Content -Path $pathNameExport
                cd $path                                                        #you need to navigate to the directory before removing the files; otherwise the directory itself will be deleted.
                Remove-Item $matchArrayList[$iii] -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue     
             }      
         } #end of $iii for-loop
    }$matchArrayList.Clear()
  }
} #end of $i for-loop
```